# segmentation fault with default constructor; vector not initialized properly

Tags: c++

When I call the default constructor Heap() in int main(), I have a feeling that I am not initializing my vector pointer properly giving me a segmentation fault. I am unsure of how to fix this issue. Below is a sample code with comments around the areas that I am having trouble (`segmentation faults` when adding elements to the `vector` using `push_back`).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A(int av, int bv):a(av),b(bv){}

  int a, b;
};

struct Heap
{
  Heap() : ptr() {}

  Heap(std::vector<A> *p) : ptr(p) {}

  void makeHeap()
  {
    heapLoc.push_back(0);
    if(ptr->size()==1){
      return;
    }

    for(int i=1; i<ptr->size(); ++i){
      heapLoc.push_back(i);
      filterUp(i);
    }
  }

  void filterUp(int idx)
  {
    int parent;
    parent = (idx-1)/2;

    while((*ptr)[heapLoc[parent]].b > (*ptr)[heapLoc[idx]].b){
      std::swap(heapLoc[parent],heapLoc[idx]);
      idx=parent;
      parent=(parent-1)/2;
    }
  }

  void pushHeap(A newA)
  {
    int idx;

    ptr->push_back(newA);  //SEGMENTATION FAULT caused by this line when calling h2.pushback(a8)
    idx=ptr->size()-1;
    heapLoc.push_back(idx);
    filterUp(idx);
  }

  std::vector<A> *ptr;
  std::vector<int> heapLoc;
};


int main()
{
  A a0(2,5), a1(4,2), a2(8,4), a3(0,3), a4(2,1),a5(2,7);  
  std::vector<A> aArray;  
  aArray.push_back(a0);
  aArray.push_back(a1);
  aArray.push_back(a2); 
  aArray.push_back(a3);
  aArray.push_back(a4);
  aArray.push_back(a5);

  Heap h(&aArray);
  h.makeHeap();

  A a8(99,1);
  h.pushHeap(a8);  //works fine

  Heap h2();
  h2.pushHeap(a8); //SEGMENTATION FAULT

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: h2's constructor is void making it's pointer a wild pointer. If you attempt to use the wild pointer you're gonna get a segmentation fault.

Comment: The pointer is uninitialized but you dereference it, what do you expect there to happen?

Comment: The pointer is initialized in the constructor. It's just set to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your default constructor should look something like this:

```
Heap() : ptr(new std::vector<A> ()) {}
```

In your current variant your ptr is initialized with some undefined value (NULL or perhaps some trash). It should be initialized with a pointer at an actual vector.

Comment: Thank you! It works. One more question. Since I declared a <code>new</code>, it is good to have an explicit destructor. This will simply be

<pre><code>
~Heap()
{
   delete ptr;
}
</code></pre>
and I should be good right? But this looks just like the default destructor.

Comment: Yes, sure, the memory should be deallocated. However just simple `delete ptr;` will lead to severe problems in case you provided a pointer from the outside (to `Heap(std::vector<A> *p)` constructor). There are at least 2 approaches how to avoid it: 1) create a flag which will show that new memory has been acquired in the default constructor (i.e. in the default constructor set it to TRUE, and set it to FALSE in the other. In the destructor use `delete` only if flag is TRUE. 2) Remove `Heap(std::vector<A> *p)` constructor, leave only the default.

Answer (score 0):

`h2.ptr` is NULL, which is why you get the segfault.